# Can't see map on NAVIT in raspberry pi

Tags: dictionary, navigation, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am following [this](http://astrobeano.blogspot.com.tr/2012/10/navit-gps-on-raspberry-pi.html) guide to install "navit" on my raspberry pi. after changing the 'navit.xml' file, I run the navit but I could not see any map. Some screen shots are below.

My navit.xml file after change the path of map. I made it

```
 <mapset enabled="yes">
                 <map type="binfile" enabled="yes" data="/home/pi/Downloads/osm_bbox_tr.bin"/>
            </mapset>
```

[image]

Here is how I run the navit:

[image]

After it starts, I see that. No map:

[image]

What is the reason of this? How can I see the map?

Answer (score 1):

Did you disable the sample map (entry just above the one you edited to point to your .bin file)? It should look like this;

```
<!-- If you dont want to use the sample map, either set enable="no" in the next line or remove the xml file from the maps directory -->
<mapset enabled="no">
<xi:include href="$NAVIT_SHAREDIR/maps/*.xml"/>
<mapset>
```

Comment: I make it 'no' but still can't see the map. My navit.xml file is in the directory of "/etc/navit". It is not in the '.bin' file. Please tell me the exact path of the 'navit.xml'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your GPSD is working(use cgps -s or gpsmon) and poiting the Center to a point belong to the map.

```
<navit center="4808 N 1134 E" zoom="256" tracking="1" orientation="-1" recent_dest="10">
```